# In which garbage container should i throw the mug from the coffee maker?

Tags: recycling

I live in Spain. In which container should I throw this - the mug from the coffee maker? It has plastic, glass and metal. The green container is for glass. The yellow container is for plastic and metal. Or should I take it to a collection point?[image]

Comment: Do you have Freecycle (freecycle.org) or similar in your area?  Re-use is the best option and someone may like to have a spare jug.  Otherwise I would take it to a collection point because heat-tolerant glass (e.g. pyrex) cannot be recycled like ordinary glass.

Comment: Thank you! I will do as instructed. Just for my own curiosity:  What happens when such an object get into the glass container? Will it screw the recycling of the rest of the glass?

Comment: "Will it screw the recycling of the rest of the glass?" - I believe so.